# Ideas to identify cutoff points for tumor classification?

Tags: classification

My lab models breast cancer in mice. I am using a 36-gene signature (derived from one of our mouse models). In the signature, all genes are elevated. I have 997 human samples and would like to apply the gene signature. All genes are weighted equally. I was thinking of ranking the samples (by adding all the gene values together), so that I could rank the samples based on this sum. The problem is: how could I establish a cut-off point for classification (i.e. after a certain rank, the human samples are not classified as "mouse-like")? This is important because I would use these "mouse-like" human samples to do further analyses. I was wondering if someone could please suggest ideas? Bootstrap resampling? Percentile analysis? Machine Learning? Or any paper doing something similar...

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What is a "36-gene signature"? What does it mean for a human to be "mouse-like" or not?

Comment: Perhaps ROC curve may be of help here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the confusion. So my lab generated a mouse model that seems to model a specific breast cancer subtype based on pathology and molecular markers. We performed gene expression analysis and tried to identify genes that were expressed similarly between human tumors, cell lines derived from human tumors and our mouse model. We found that there were 36 genes that were commonly elevated (i.e. signature). We want to use this signature to identify human samples that resemble our mouse model based on gene expression. I hope that I am clearer. Please let met know if you have other questions.